# Spring REST @RequestMapping Extract Incorrectly If Value Contains ‘.’

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**Problem:**

See following Spring REST example, if a request such as `http://localhost:8080/site/google.com` is submitted, Spring returns “**google**“. Look like Spring treats “.” as file extension, and extract half of the parameter value.

Spring must return “**google.com**“. How can do it?

**SiteController.java**

```
package com.example.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/site")
public class SiteController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{domain}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome(@PathVariable("domain") String domain,
    ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("domain", domain);
    return "domain";

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use regex in the path variable of the @ResourceMapping.  For instance, you could do

```
{domain:.[\\S]*}
```

You will probably have to fiddle with the regex some to get it right.  The ':' separates the path variable name from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple just add ":.+" with your parameter like below:

here username is e-mail id

```
@RequestMapping(value = "checkuser/{username:.+}" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
boolean getUserName(@PathVariable("username") String userName){ 
    boolean isUserAvailable = userDao.checkAvailable(userName); 
    return isUserAvailable; 
}
```

I am passing value from URL like : 
baseurl/checkuser/test@test.com

Answer (score 0):

just make sure your url end of '/'and SiteController.java chage noting..

`change http://xxx/site/google.com to http://xxx/site/google.com/`